# Vim: run commands depending on file directory

Tags: vim, vimrc, nvim

In my `init.vim`, I want to run certain commands only if the current file is under a certain hierarchy. Pseudo-code:

```
if current_file_directory == ~/some/path/here
  autocmd <whatever>
  set <whatever>
endif
```

But all the `if` examples I’m finding are too basic to extrapolate.

To clarify, neither `:pwd` nor `getcwd()` apply, because those return the directory one is in when invoking neovim. I care about the directory the file is in. Following the code above, the commands should fire if I’m under `/tmp` but editing the file `~/some/path/here/more/deep/still.txt` but *not* if I’m under `~/some/path/here` but editing the file `/tmp/example.txt`.

Answer (score 3):

Based on [@muru’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/660267/49593) and further testing, the final code would be:

```
if expand('%:h') =~ 'some/path/here'
  autocmd <whatever>
  set <whatever>
endif
```

- `expand('%:h')` gives the directory’s path to the file without the home directory.
- `=~` is required for the partial match.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`expand()`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html?#expand%28%29) on the filename (`%`) with [various modifiers](https://vimhelp.org/cmdline.txt.html?#filename-modifiers) (`:p`, `:h`, etc.):

```
:e ~/some/path/here/more/deep/still.txt
:echo expand("%:ph")
/home/muru/some/path/here/more/deep/still.txt
```

You can compare that to your desired path.

Comment: I did find some references to `expand`, but I’m unclear on how to use it in the required `if` context inside `init.vim`. Could you provide an example?

Comment: @user137369 You put `expand("%:ph")` instead of `current_file_directory` in your `if` command.